# Onload a menu tab

Tags: jquery, html, onload

I have a menu in my webpage and currently, a user have to click the menu tabs to view them, i want one of them to load automatically when the website is launched.

- I named the anchor which holds that tab as "Home".

What should i add to the `<body>` tag to achieve it?

The menu items:

```
<body>
        <div id="mb_background" class="mb_background">
            <img class="mb_bgimage" src="images/default.jpg" alt="Background"/>
            <div class="mb_overlay"></div>
            <div class="mb_loading"></div>
            <div id="logoside"><img src="img/4yearslogoside.png"></div>

        </div>
        <div id="mb_pattern" class="mb_pattern"></div>

        <div id="mb_menu" class="mb_menu">
            <a id="home" href="#" data-speed="1000" data-easing="easeOutBack">בית</a>
            <a href="#" data-speed="1000" data-easing="easeOutBack">האנגר 17</a>
            <a href="#" data-speed="1000" data-easing="easeInExpo">טראנס ישראל</a>
            <a href="#" data-speed="1000" data-easing="easeOutBack">ליין-אפ</a>
            <a href="#" data-speed="1000" data-easing="easeInExpo">כרטיסים</a>
        </div>
```

[The Webpage](http://www.tranceil.co.il/events/4years/main)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try simulating a click on that element using jquery's `.trigger()` function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#home').trigger('click');
});
```

Make sure to add the trigger code **after** the `mb_menu` items have had a click event attached.

Or, to cut down on extra code, you could add a little to your current event handler - like this:

```
$menuItems.bind('click', function(e) {
    /* your current code here, no changes */
}).first().trigger('click');
```

Comment: thank you for your help..how should i put that into the body tag? or i'm not supposed to?!

Comment: I can see you've just added my code, you'll need to place it right at the bottom after all the other scripts, just before `</body>`.

Comment: Yup..that did the trick :) thank you my friend.. ill accept the answer after the 5 minuete block is over

Comment: @TonalDev - Or you could edit your existing code and put: `$menuItems.bind('click', function(e) { /* your current code here */ }).first().trigger('click');`. That would remove the need for the extra script tag.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#home').click();
}
```